# Mapply over multiple Google Analytics API queries in Shiny app

Tags: r, google-analytics-api, shiny-server, shiny

I'm looking to `mapply` over multiple [Google Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) queries in a [Shiny](http://www.shinyapps.io/) app, using 3 input variables dictated by each row of a data frame. To access the Google Analytics API through R, am using the CRAN [RGA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGA/RGA.pdf) library.

In my `ui.R`, I have `textOutput` mapped to each `i` in `df$name`. This way, `output$name` should render the results of both queries for each `i` in `df$name`.

Currently, my console prints:

> "No results were obtained."

I have tested the queries individually, and they both should pull results.

This is a reduced version of my server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  library(RGA)
  thisWeekEnd<-"2016-01-17"
  thisWeekStart<-as.character(as.Date(thisWeekEnd)-7)
  lastWeekEnd<-as.character(as.Date(thisWeekEnd)-8)
  lastWeekStart<-as.character(as.Date(thisWeekEnd)-13)
  startOfCampaign<-"2015-12-23"

  df <- data.frame(
    start= c(thisWeekStart,lastWeekStart,startOfCampaign),
    end =c(thisWeekEnd,lastWeekEnd,thisWeekEnd),
    name=c("thisWeek","lastWeek","total"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  gaData<-function(start,end,name){

    query1 <- get_ga(
      id,
      start.date = start, 
      end.date = end,
      metrics = "ga:sessions",
      )

    query2 <- get_ga(
      id,
      start.date = start, 
      end.date = end,
      metrics = "ga:uniqueEvents",
      )

   output$name<-renderText({
        paste(as.character(query1$sessions)," sessions",
        as.character(query2$unique.events)," unique events"
        )})
  }

  mapply(gaData, df$start,df$end,df$name)
}
```

Comment: This code works for me: https://gist.github.com/artemklevtsov/c510c0a7737bf7215099

Comment: The code works through R, but in a shiny app, no results are pulled. I think my problem is enclosing the paste function with output$name<-renderText({}), so that the output is routed to a dynamic element in the UI for each df$name.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand the question:

```
library(shiny)
library(RGA)
authorize()
id <- "ga:100202885"
getDates <- function() {
    today <- Sys.Date()
    thisWeekStart <- as.Date(cut(today, "weeks"))
    thisWeekEnd <- as.Date(cut(today, "weeks")) + 6
    lastWeekStart <- thisWeekStart - 7
    lastWeekEnd <- thisWeekEnd - 7
    startOfCampaign <- as.Date("2015-12-23")
    data.frame(
        start = c(thisWeekStart, lastWeekStart, startOfCampaign),
        end = c(thisWeekEnd, lastWeekEnd, thisWeekEnd),
        row.names = c("thisWeek", "lastWeek","total"),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
getData <- function(start, end, ...) {
    get_ga(..., start.date = start, end.date = end, "ga:sessions,ga:uniqueEvents")

}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    title = "Test RGA input",
    tableOutput("data")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    GAData <- NULL
    dates <- getDates()
    GAData <- cbind(df, t(mapply(getData, dates$start, dates$end, profileId = id)))
    output$data <- renderTable({
        validate(need(!is.null(GAData), "Loading data..."))
        GAData
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```